# Fetching a custom header of a request (Java HTTP)

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to implement a get request of a webpage through Java (using Apache HTTP API).

The webpage is sending an custom header value in the get request which i am not able to simulate in the java code.

When i open a webpage it sends a request header "AO-7DEABF" with some auto-generated value (value is consistent for a login session), and the web page would not respond unless i send the same value through my java code.

How do i fetch the actual value from a web-page from my java code, so that i can send it along with my request.

Sample Code im am using

```
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        Executor executor = Executor.newInstance(client).use(cookieStore);

        String url = "www.sampleurl.com";
        Request req = Request.Get(url);
        String response = executor.execute(request).returnContent().asString();
    }
}
```

Request Header

```
GET /rest/zephyr/latest/zql/executeSearch/?zqlQuery=&offset=20&maxRecords=0&expand=executionStatus&_=1444386966596 HTTP/1.1
Host: jira.devops.mnscorp.net
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
AO-7DEABF: Vwl8V0kdk7Xvyq9BFivbLpbSdpZ2tFjy182i1qYBju0o0KyWAPh9chbJvt9GRGvvf98RK8u1GHaclCm8FBEhbA==
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://<myclientjira>/secure/enav/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: wb48617274=C9B5D1A8; seraph.rememberme.cookie=24122%3A41d5dae1cd459348abecfb0ca5feee6766fd0ac0; JSESSIONID=1428066D5584823DFD572189A2456540; atlassian.xsrf.token=BSMP-3NDP-M3AB-8R70|98ba98938704a930babccb4a5912c01b762d9220|lin; wb48617274=90986387
```

Comment: How you getting the HTTP request? using Servlets? better if you can share your code.

Comment: i a using http client api, update the quest with code

Comment: you can take header details from response as below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take the header details in the response as below.

```
//get all headers       
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
for (Header header : headers) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
}

//get header by 'key'
String server = response.getFirstHeader("xxxx").getValue();
```

Comment: Sorry Janath, i guess u mis-understood. I need to send it in the request for me to get any response. It is sent only in request header of the webpage, but not available in response header (Saw it in Google Chrome Inspect)

Comment: Can you share the request header send by web page?

Comment: Since you do not aware the logic behind the auto generated value, as a alternative, you can take the key value pair from web browser and use them in the java code. Otherwise you have to find logic for generate that value.

Comment: Got it from web browser output. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you do is sending some Zephyr-related stuff. And yes, using 'usual' Zehpyr API (not ZAPI) requires this value of "AO-7DEABF" sent every time.

You can get the header value by just GETting the home page of your Jira, after you logged in. The page code will contain a chunk like:

```
var zEncKeyFld = \"AO-7DEABF\";\r\n\t\t
var zEncKeyVal = \"QNZa3bygsZ4Jfu+Xw91TcNnRV2yJUj5/Wiu1+l5vowsg/WCjy11kuUACnS/OFIvWuR3NITQFhO46LxZubp/EWw==\";\r\n
```

And then it's your steps to parse it out. The rules how this peace in generated are unknown to me, this is a workaround I found.